# Is there a way to call varying function of member object based on template variable

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following code:

```
class Person {
  void func1() {
    obj_.function1();
  }

  void func2() {
    obj_.function2();
  }

  void func3() {
    obj_.function3();
  }

  Object obj_;
};
```

It's pretty obvious there is a pattern here...

I would like to know if I can call different functions based on template argument.
the functions inside Object are regular member functions.

Is there any way to do something like the following?

```
class Person {
  
  template <typename Func>
  void generic() {
    obj_.Func();
  } 

  Object obj_;
};
```

Another question: Is there a type for function?

I believe it's the key point for it's doable or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 template <auto Func>
 void generic() {
   (obj_.*Func)();
 }
```

Then `foo.generic<&Object::function1>()` calls function1.

Prior to [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17):

```
 template <void (Object::*Func)()>
 void generic() {
   (obj_.*Func)();
 }
```

should work.

Comment: There is an error while calling: candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly specified argument for template parameter 'Func'

Comment: @guy You may have typos, other details different, because both of the above compile when I copy paste them into a c++ compiler (and add a `Object` with that method called `obj_`).

Comment: thanks, it works indeed. probably caused by one of additions to the code..